# How to add Outlook to "Share" popup menu in finder

Tags: macos, finder, automation

Unfortunately I have an old habit to have the "send by email" when right click on a file in the Share option pop up window.

I would prefer to use the Outlook so I can email the selected file.

Right now it comes up with Twitter, Facebook, Messages, AirDrop and even with Flicker (that I do not have).

Is that option available on my MBA osx 10.8.3 ?

Answer (score 6):

Automator services lets you add a new service to accomplish this.

See my screen capture for specific details how easy this is showing my first time using Automator.

[image: Automator workflow]

Important is to select your email service of your choice (gmail in my case) to send messages and attachments.

That will tell the OS X Mail client to use that service to send emails.

Save your Automator service file (give it a easy name you want to appear in the Finders right click popup window). Something like "Send file by email".

Now when I right click on a file in Finder it shows that service at the bottom of the popup window. Now just follow the instruction and see it work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to actually open a new Outlook message. There is an action called Create New Outlook Mail Message.

Answer (score 2):

You were very close. But New Mail Message uses Apple Mail, not Outlook. To use Outlook you can use the Create New Outlook Mail Message action.

1. In OSX El Cap:
2. Command-Space for Spotlight
3. Automator
4. Command-N for "New" if it doesn't come up automatically
5. Select Service
6. Create the steps according to the screenshot below.

[image]

**The action is now available under Services when you right click a file.**

Result looks like:

[image]

Comment: I can't seem to find any actions with the filter "Outlook" in macOS Sierra or El Capitan. Do I need to do something to get them to show up?

Comment: Same here. I recall getting this to work in the past but it was on a different Macbook.

Answer (score 1):

PS.  this will work with Outlook directly if you instead click on "Mail" in the far left pane under Library, then drag the "Create New Outlook Mail Message" to the right pane.  You will change above settings to "Files and Folders" in "Finder" but this will make it work in Outlook without having to configure or use MacMail at all.