# Is there any way to add Slack to the Share menu on a Mac?

Tags: macos, finder, sharing, slack

Pretty simple, I'd like to right click on a file, select `Share >` and have Slack be one of the sharing options. When I go into `More...` Slack is not an option.

I want to share a file over Slack with a coworker from the finder.

Comment: I bet [Automator in your hands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/246041/5472) will work well, here. Unless slack’s non-native app has zero hooks to select the recipient, you should have leverage to avoid needing to drag and drop the file.

Answer (score 4):

No, only applications that provide Activity Views show up in the list.

The best you can use is the `Share` menu's `Copy Link` option.

The fix for this would require slack to do a moderate amount of engineering work to register an app extension to enable this Activity View

- https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/components/menus-and-actions/activity-views/
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/app_extension_support

[Automator does allow you to customize the share sheets](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/87486/5472), so that might work great if you want to preselect Slack when copying url to the file from finder and have that custom action show up right where you want it.